# Move folder content up one level

Tags: shell, rename

I have a directory that is unpacked, but is in a folder.  How can I move the contents up one level? I am accessing CentOS via SSH.

Answer (score 314):

With the folder called 'myfolder' and up one level in the file hierarchy (the point you want it to put) the command would be:

```
mv myfolder/* .
```

So for example if the data was in `/home/myuser/myfolder` then from `/home/myuser/` run the command.

Comment: You may need to also match `.*` not just `*` if the archive contained dot-files. Also add ` && rmdir myfolder` to the end o that to remove the now extraneous folder. This is save because it will only run if the mv returns success AND because rmdir will not remove a non-empty directory.

Comment: Good point on the `.*`.  Removing the original folder is both trivial and not asked for so we'll let OP deal with that him/herself.

Comment: @Caleb is it possible to write both ``*`` and ``.*`` in one line? just curiosity

Comment: @Richard Yes, it is. The arguments for `mv` will all be sources except the LAST argument which needs to be the target for moving (and in the case of multiple sources, needs to be a folder).

Comment: tested, and it works.

Comment: I am getting bash: `/bin/mv: Argument list too long`

Comment: What happens, if `myfolder` contains a subdirectory called `myfolder`? That wouldn't work. Is there any clean way of avoiding this, or tell mv to ignore this or replace the source in that case?

Comment: if you are in the folder that you need to move everything up one level, then use mv * ../.

Comment: How about nested dirs with same name i.e. exercisism/cli/cli and the problem to move cli (last) one level up?

Comment: Worth noting this doesn't seem to work for hidden files (displayed with the "-a" flag) such as .gitignore

Comment: Justin: yes, and that's why @kenorb's answer is the best one.

Answer (score 59):

Just to make it crystal clear, taken from Rudu's answer above, and the comments.

If you need to move all the contents, INCLUDING files that start with a . (like .htaccess, .git, etc), you need to include both * and .* in your command.  Like so:

```
 mv subfolder/* subfolder/.* .
```

That will move contents of subfolder to your current folder.  Note the space before the last ".".

Comment: it works but I get `mv: rename fake/. to ./.: Invalid argument` and `mv: rename fake/.. to ./..: Invalid argument`

Comment: If you are unsure about target folder have both folder and files inside then run command separately otherwise it will prompt: "no matches found"

Answer (score 28):

This is possible with the following methods:

- Using `rsync`:

  ```
  rsync -vua --delete-after foo/ .
  ```
- Using `cp` and `rmdir`:

  ```
  cp -vaR foo/. . && rmdir foo/
  ```
- Using `mv` (with `dotglob` option enabled):

  ```
  shopt -s dotglob # Includes filenames beginning with a dot.
  mv -- foo/* .    # Where foo/ is the folder consisting the files.
  shopt -u dotglob # Disables previously enabled dotglob option.
  ```

  where `foo/` is your folder whose content is to be moved one level up.

  <sup>See: `help shopt` and `man bash`.</sup>
- Using `mv` (as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/62154/87805)):

  ```
  mv foo/* foo/.[^.]* . && rmdir foo/
  ```

  <sup>Note: It would miss a file called `foo/..bar..`.</sup>

  <sup>Note: For POSIX shells, you need `[!.]`.</sup>

Comment: What are the rsync switches `-v`, `-u`, `-a` and `-r` doing? AFAICT, `-v` is verbose, which just makes rsync print more information. `-u` means update - only copy a file if it is newer. That doesn't seem relevant. `-a` means archive. That will copy the owner and permissions of the file, and make the sync recursive. `-r` means recursive, but that's already covered by `-a`.

Comment: `-u` is useful when you don't want to spent extra time of moving data which is already there (especially for slow storage devices). I've removed `-r`, since it's covered by `-a` as you mentioned.

Comment: `mv foo/* foo/.[^.]* .` would miss a file called `foo/..bar..` for instance. Note that for POSIX shells, you need `[!.]`.

Comment: It should be mentioned, that `rsync -vua --delete-after foo/ .` deletes everything else that might already exists in the current directory.

Comment: I don't see how the `cp` suggestion will work? It only copies the files, not moves them, and then `rmdir` will fail because "foo" directory is not empty.

Comment: I do love your idea of making use of the `dotglob` shell option to make the `mv /* .` solution work for all files -- very elegant! But I think you also meant to `&& rmdir foo` afterwards.

Comment: One big disadvantage of `rsync` seems to be that it actually copies the files, which is very expensive for large files. `mv` just changes pointers.

Answer (score 12):

just issue an mv command

```
mv (directory)/* .
```

if you want to delete the directory then add

```
rm -rf (directory)
```

Assumed that you are in a parent directory of (directory)

If you are inside the (directory) then

```
mv * ../
```

Comment: Additional safety tip: When deleting a directory you know should be empty, `rmdir` complains and exits if the directory *isn't* empty, while `rm -r` would instead just have deleted it and all its contents. (It's a [poka-yoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poka-yoke).)

Comment: Great point! I can't think of a reason not to do it that way.

Comment: @MarkLalor One reason might be the presence of hidden files, like the ubiquitous `.DS_store` in macOS. The `mv` command above won't move those (without `dotglob` set).

Comment: The `mv` invocation as written will miss dot files, and the `rm -rf` one is unsafe. If the move worked correctly, you should be able to just `rmdir` the source directory because it will be empty.

Answer (score 3):

i have one short hand command

```
cp */* .
```

this will copy all subfolders content on level up 
of course you can use move

```
mv */* .
```

or assign new distenation

```
cp */* /destination
```

Answer (score 3):

If you get the "Argument list too long" error by using `mv * ../` I suggest doing this instead:

```
find . -name '*.*' -exec mv {} ../ \;
```

- `find`: search a folder
- `-name`: match a desired criteria
- `-exec`: run the command that follows
- `{}`: insert the filename found
- `\;`: mark the end of the exec command

Answer (score 3):

The question doesn't specify what shell, so here's a **zsh** variant:

```
mv myfolder/*(D) .
```

`(D)` ensures both dot and non-dot files are included, but, crucially, not the `.` and `..` objects. It's equivalent to kenorb's dotglob solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think surely the best answer is:

```
mv myfolder/mysubfolder .
```

Occasaionally you have the problem that both folders have the same name

```
mv myfolder myfolder.old 
mv myfolder.old/myfolder . 
rmdir myfolder.old
```

Comment: This is only moving one specific subfolder up one level, unlike what's requested, so no, this isn't the best answer.

Answer (score -1):

for those of you on a shared server you'd have to use something like this

To move the files

`mv -v ~/public_html/public_html/* ~/public_html/`

To copy the files

`cp -a ~/public_html/public_html/* ~/public_html/`

Comment: The question above asks about moving not copying contents. This would duplicate the files by leaving the originals in a subfolder. Also being a "shared" server or not really doesn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: your right and here is the answer for it...

Comment: Re your edit: how is that any different that [the already upvoted answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19345/1925)? And what does a "shared server" have to do with it? Please [edit] to explain these items if this is going to be a useful contribution that adds value to what is already here.

Comment: I disagree about the shared server not having nothing to do with it. The way the "dir" is entered makes a world of a difference..

Comment: dude why you so mad?... wow.. I was just sharing a little knowledge. We all understand differently and confront different technical problems differently... Have yourself a good day Caleb..